# How to assign an int value to an arraylist item

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
ArrayList<Book> books=new ArrayList<Book>();
Book b1=new Book();
b1.setName("Physics");
b1.setCopy(10);
books.add(b1);
b1.setName("Physics");
b1.setCopy(10);
books.add(b1);
b1.setName("Differential Calculus");
b1.setCopy(10);
books.add(b1);
b1.setName("Integral Calculus");
b1.setCopy(10);
books.add(b1);
b1.setName("Introduction to English");
b1.setCopy(10);
books.add(b1);
b1.setName("History of the Philippines");
b1.setCopy(10);
books.add(b1);
b1.setName("Java for beginners");
b1.setCopy(10);
books.add(b1);
b1.setName("Cisco");
b1.setCopy(10);
books.add(b1);
b1.setName("Animal Kingdom");
b1.setCopy(10);
books.add(b1);
b1.setName("College Algebra");
b1.setCopy(10);
books.add(b1);
b1.setName("Trigonometry");
b1.setCopy(10);
books.add(b1);
```

I'm trying to do this

```
for(Book book : books)
{
    System.out.println(book.getName() + " " + String.valueOf(book.getCopy()) + "copies");
}
String borrow=scan.next();
if(borrow.equals("physics"))
{
    int copies=10;
    System.out.println("The book you borrowed is Physics.");
    System.out.println("You borrowed copy "+stack.pop()+" of Physics");
    copies--;
    bbooks.add("Physics");
    System.out.println("Physics only has "+copies+" copies left.");
}
```

The output is:

> Trigonometry 10copies
>   Trigonometry 10copies
>   Trigonometry 10copies
>   Trigonometry 10copies
>   Trigonometry 10copies
>   Trigonometry 10copies
>   Trigonometry 10copies
>   Trigonometry 10copies
>   Trigonometry 10copies
>   Trigonometry 10copies

Comment: **1** Please add a tag for the programming language. **2** Not sure what you try to do. Converting an array into an object?

Comment: what is the type of books? can you show a complete example? what is your goal? do you wantto be able to fetch a book based on copied or vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a custom `Java` class called `Book`. add two class variables, `String name;` and `int copies`. Setup getters and setters.

```
public class Book {
    private String name;
    private int copy;


    public Book() {

    }

    //Add this constructor, and keep the empty constructor too

    public Book(String name, int copy) {
        this.name = name;
        this.copy = copy;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setCopy(int copy) {
        this.copy = copy;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getCopy() {
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Then from the `Main` class :

```
ArrayList<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
```

**Method 1 :**

```
Book b1 = new Book();
b1.setName("Physics");
b1.setCopy(10);
bookList.add(b1);

Book b2 = new Book();
//b2.setName....
//do this for all books
```

**Method 2: use this method. This is a more efficient way :**

```
bookList.add(new Book("Trigonometry", 10));
bookList.add(new Book("Differential Calculus", 10));
//Do this for all books.
```

This part stays the same :

```
int index = 1;
for(Book book : bookList) {
    System.out.println(index + " " + book.getName() + " " + String.valueOf(book.getCopy()) + "copies");
    index++;
}



int borrow = scan.nextInt();
if(borrow==0){
    System.out.println("The book you borrowed is Physics.");

    Book book = (Book) bookList.get(borrow);
    book.setCopy((book.getCopy() - 1));
}
```

I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Why does the `book.getName` only displays the last book?

Comment: how many books have you added to the list? It is inside the enhanced for loop, and should one by one display the names of all the books.

Comment: i added 10 books. this is what i did

`System.out.println("What book do you want to borrow? Select from the list.");
                    for(Book book : books)
                    {
                        int copies=book.getCopy();
                       
                            System.out.println(book.getName() + " " + String.valueOf(book.getCopy()) + "copies");
                        int borrow=scan.nextInt();`

Comment: You cannot put the scan statement in the for loop. It prints the first book, and then waits for the input. Put the scan.nextInt() command outside the for loop.

Comment: but the problem now is the 10 books has only one title and it is the last book that i added. can't figure out the problem there

Comment: Check my updated answer. Check the code for the Main Class. I think this is what you are looking for. But I will recommend using a Switch Case instead of multiple if statements. Show me the code where you added the books.

Comment: i already did the code that you last edited but still all the books are trigonometry and all copies of the books are subtracted by one every time i borrow one

Comment: This should works, but to be unambiguous, for each time, use a new book object.
Book b2 = new Book();
b2.setName(); etc.. for each new book, make a new object. and add it.

Comment: Better still, go through my edited updated answer, make a new Constructor using fields and use the Method 2 that I have added, to add the books to the booklist. This has to work! I have tested it. It works.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an HashMap instead of a list.

it would be something like:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

map.put("Differential Calculus", 10);
map.put("Physics", 12);
map.put("Integral Calculus", 20);
```

Or keep using a list and create a class like this:

```
public class Subject {
    private String name;
    private int copies;

    public Subject(String name, int copies) {
        this.name = name;
        this.copies = copies;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getCopies() {
        return copies;
    }
}
```

This way you could use a list...

```
ArrayList<Subject> list = new ArrayList<Subject>();

list.add(new Subject("Differential Calculus", 10));
list.add(new Subject("Physics", 12));
list.add(new Subject("Integral Calculus", 20));
```